# Unable to play sounds (mp3 files within the app bundle) using a .onTapGesture

Tags: swift, xcode, audio, swiftui, mp3

this is pretty much my first attempt at coding my first app and I am essentially still learning the foundations. I am building a flash card based animals app, where images are displayed from an array (with parsed data from a local JSON file). Each object of the animals contains the name, image name, and sound names as strings. I coded a function to call playSound() from within my cardView that when tapped will play the corresponding sound of the animal object (using an index based for loop). This worked perfectly fine until my files went out of sync and had to be coded again. However, the code looks identical to me and I cannot seem to get the sounds to play at all. Any help will be appreciated.

The code snippet from my cardView's body view:

```
GeometryReader { geo in 

TabView {    ForEach (0..<model.animals.count, id: \.self) { index in
                        
                        ZStack {
                            Rectangle()
                                .foregroundColor(.white)
                            VStack {
                                Image(model.animals[index].image)
                                    .resizable()
                                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                                Text(model.animals[index].name)

                                    .foregroundColor(.black)
                                    .font(.title)
                                    .padding(.bottom, 10)
                            }
                            .onTapGesture {
                             playSound(sound: model.animals[index].sound, type: "mp3")
                            }
                        }
                        .frame(width: geo.size.width - 40, height: geo.size.height - 50, alignment: .center)
                        .cornerRadius(10)
                        .shadow(color: .black, radius: 10, x: -5, y: 5)
                        
                    }
                }
                .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle(indexDisplayMode: .never))
                .indexViewStyle(PageIndexViewStyle(backgroundDisplayMode: .never))
            }
```

My playSound function is coded as follows in its own swift file in the bundle:

```
import Foundation
import AVFoundation

var audioPlayer: AVAudioPlayer?

func playSound(sound: String, type: String) {
    if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: sound, ofType: type) {
        do {
            audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: path))
            audioPlayer?.play()
        }
        catch {
            print("Could not find and play the sound file.")
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried running through a previous project with identical playSound() method call albeit for a different application (another flashcard based app looping through an array of objects). Although the playSound method is identical, it does not work for my code above. Any help or direction will be most appreciated. Also, I appreciate I may not be explaining very well or may need to clarify further, and I am happy to do this if needed. Your patience with my ignorance will be appreciated.

Comment: your code works fine with me. Are you sure it finds the sounds in the bundle?

Comment: an unrelated tip: you should not use indices in the ForEach, but instead do `ForEach (model.animals, id: \.self) { animal in` and then use e.g. `animal.name`

Comment: Hey Chris, that's what I thought but still no luck. The sound files are definitely in the bundle (i.e., they are in the same root folder of my app file and located within a subfolder (sounds) and can be seen in the navigator. I can also click each sound individually and use the in built Xcode player and these work fine, so totally baffled as to why they are not playing in the app...

And thank you for the side tip - this seems more intuitive for sure.

Comment: hmm, does it play at least the first sound, ore none at all? As said, it did work in my simple test with one sound.

Comment: Chris, I misunderstood your first comment. I have double checked to see if it could find the sound files despite them being there and heck they absolutely couldn't. Put fatalError print if URL could not be found and have had to manually add each sound file into build phases' copy bundle resources, which is a bit cluttered and messy but functional nonetheless. Thank you so much. It is now working as it should! P..s., silly question perhaps but is there a way I can say my question has been answered? Thank you again and have a lovely rest of your day/evening.

Comment: not really, because I didn't submit a formal answer. You can click the little up arrow on my comment :) And of course you can answer your own question when you found a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I've been facing hte same issue and looked into multiple places i implemented this piece of code

```
do{
   let alertSound = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "test", ofType: "wav")!)
   try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSession.Category.playback)
   try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true, options: [])
   player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: alertSound as URL)
   player.prepareToPlay()
   player.play()
}catch{
   print(error)
}
```

For me changing the file from mp3 to wav made this piece of code work. I'm not sure why the audio file can't get rendered when it's on mp3 file but it worked for me. Hope it helps!